Using .isin on columns to categorize data
I am working in Databricks and fairly new to PySpark. I have a table we pulled in from SQL with several columns whose values we've concatenated into a single column called edu_hist which we then want to take and in a new column called edu_level label it with the corresponding education level.
I am attempting to use .isin to achieve this, but my code is just labeling everything UNKNOWN. Where am I making a misstep?
original table (df)
| id  | edu_hist     |
|-----|--------------|
| 123 | , , T, 3, 6  |
| 456 | , 7, X, 4, , |
| 789 | , 3, S, 2, , |

.isin code to label
df = df.withColumn('edu_level', 
  F.when((F.col('edu_hist').isin('7', '8', '9', 'Z')), 'GRADUATE DEGREE') 
   .when((F.col('edu_hist').isin('5', '6', 'W', 'X', 'Y')), 'COLLEGE DEGREE') 
   .when((F.col('edu_hist').isin('3', '4', 'V')), 'SOME COLLEGE') 
   .when((F.col('edu_hist').isin('S', 'T', 'U')), 'HIGH SCHOOL OR EQUIVALENT') 
   .when((F.col('edu_hist').isin('0', '1', '2', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R')), 'OTHER').otherwise('UNKNOWN')
  )

expected output
| id  | edu_hist     | edu_level       |
|-----|--------------|-----------------|
| 123 | , , T, 3, 6  | COLLEGE DEGREE  |
| 456 | , 7, X, 4, , | GRADUATE DEGREE |
| 789 | , 3, S, 2, , | SOME COLLEGE    |

actual output
| id  | edu_hist     | edu_level |
|-----|--------------|-----------|
| 123 | , , T, 3, 6  | UNKNOWN   |
| 456 | , 7, X, 4, , | UNKNOWN   |
| 789 | , 3, S, 2, , | UNKNOWN   |


what is the data type of that column?

@samkart it is a string

is it really a string (", , T, 3, 6") or an array of strings (["","" , "T", "3", "6"])?
